# is there any machanism to calculate rendering time of a page in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

as part of performance analysis we are able to calculate server side processing time and data down loading time but no idea how to calculate page rendering time in our hybrid mobile app(developed in ionic and angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

Track for platform ready event:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']).run(function($ionicPlatform) { 
    var start = performance.now();
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        console.log("App ready after" + (performance.now() - start) + " milliseconds.")
    };
});
```

Also you can track every view load time using this:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function (viewInfo, state) {
    console.log('VIEW LOADED', viewInfo, state);
})
```